# Store mapping with multiple conditions in database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

I have a SELECT-Statement where ich have to map keys. I Need to store this mapping an a database because this mapping can Change. As the mapping-condition is only base on one key, it is relativly simple.

```
SELECT 
  table.flield1 AS COL1
, (SELECT value from TransformationTable WHERE key = table.field2) AS COL2
[...]
```

Now i have a case where the mapping-condition is more complicated. In SQL it is like:

```
CASE
 WHEN table.field1 = 'ORG' AND table.field2 IN (1,2,3) THEN 01
 WHEN table.field1 = 'ORG' AND table.field2 NOT IN (5,76,88) OR IN (9) THEN 02
 WHEN table.field1 != 'ORG' AND table.field2 IN (1,2,3) THEN 03
END
```

How can I store such condition in a database so that I can select the value like in example 1.

Does some one have an idea?

Comment: When you say the mappings can change what do you mean? Which part of the rule/code is changeable?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially to perform this task you need something that can evaluate an expression for you on the fly.  The only ways I have solved this kind of problem in the past are:

1. Easy to implement but less flexible: embed the expression in a view then query from the view; change view as mapping expression changes.  Remember a view is just a stored SQL statement and a SQL statement can contain and evaluate complex expressions.
2. Harder to implement but more  flexible: store a lexical construct for the expression in a table somewhere; then read in that "expression" and use it to generate the SQL dynamically; then run the dynamically generated SQL.

Have fun!!!

Answer (score 0):

If You want a table solution, then I think of something like this:

```
PARENT      | CHILD         | LOGICAL   | COLUMN        | OPERATOR  | VALUES  | OUTPUT    |
OPERATOR ID | OPERATOR ID   | OPERATOR  | (expression)  | OPERATOR  | VALUES  | ATTRIBUTE |
--------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
10001       | 10003         | AND       | field1        | IN        | 1,2,3   | 01        |
10001       | 10004         | AND       | field2        | NOT IN    | 5,76,88 | 01        |
10002       | 10005         |           | field1        | IN        | ...     | 02        |
10002       | 10006         |           | field2        | NOT IN    | ...     | 02        |
```

Columns `PARENT OPERATOR ID` and `CHILD OPERATOR ID` are additional, in case You need *nested* AND-OR operators `( ... AND ( ... OR ... AND ( ... OR ... ) ) )`